# Image URL and pagination

Tags: php, image, codeigniter, pagination

I am developing an image gallery site. Now I want to have unique URL for every image, like:

```
www.xyz.com/photos/aaaa.jpg
```

I am using CodeIgniter to implement pagination.

Pagination works fine, but I am getting a URL like:

```
/index.php/main/latest/5
```

I can remove pagination and get this URL, `www.xyz.com/photos/aaaa.jpg` but how can I go to the next/previous images? I am showing images on the basis of created date and have search functionality.

So I can I implement distinct URL and have pagination. So if any one can share an image and can navigate prev/next.

For example http://www.imdb.com/media/rm397582592/rg117676544, and you can still go to next/previous in this gallary.

Comment: Did you read the documentation on routing?

Comment: Thanks Cryprtic for your reply. can you please send me a link of doc or point out, where this kind of problem might be solved. I am new to php and codeIgniter? or can you suggest me any book?

Comment: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html

Comment: pagination urls and image urls are two different things :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you misunderstanding pagination and images urls:

pagination url looks like:

```
site.com/photos/3 /*where 3 is the pagination number of page or page offset*/
```

while image proper link looks like:

```
site.com/img/myimage.jpg
```

image link is a separated page or popup if you show image inside javascript popup for example

so you get 1 gallery page in which you paginate all images, once you click on a single image you get the single image page

so pagination links has nothing in common with the single image url

Comment: if I user site.com/img/myimage.jpg , how can I user next and previous button, if I am on this image page

Comment: @user1494642 you CAN'T use own image url as pagination urls, they are two different urls

Comment: Thank you okok.. but How can I create my url and go to next image of that url by created date or by rating.

Comment: @user1494642 you can easly take a look to some good pagination tutorial here for example :http://phpmaster.com/pagination-with-codeigniter/

Comment: remember you have url params, you can use and combine them as like as you want